# Images are not getting displayed in phonegap android platform

Tags: android, cordova

Images dont show up when I add

```
<img src="sharepoint public url">
```

in phonegap android platform. I have access origin to * with properties like launch-external="yes" subdomains="true". Please help

Comment: You'd probably need to specifically [whitelist](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html) certain domains because allowing access origin to `*` is way too liberal.

Answer (score 0):

```
<access subdomains="true" uri="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

Try adding these 2 line of codes to your config.xml file

Comment: Would this still work if I am trying to fetch the image from a sharepoint library?